# Google cloud & laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, google-app-engine

I'm trying to make laravel 5.2 app work on google cloud services and getting this error.

> ErrorException: file_put_contents(/app/bootstrap/cache/services.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:109

i've deployed app following this instruction https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-laravel-on-appengine-flexible and using https://github.com/shpasser/GaeSupportL5

My app.yaml file

```
runtime: php
env: flex

runtime_config:
document_root: ''

# required on some platforms so ".env" is not skipped
skip_files: false

env_variables:
# The values here will override those in ".env". This is useful for
# production-specific configuration. However, feel free to set these 
values
# in ".env" instead if you prefer.
APP_LOG: errorlog
STORAGE_DIR: /tmp
#CACHE_DRIVER: database
#SESSION_DRIVER: database
## Set these environment variables according to your CloudSQL 
configuration.
DB_HOST: localhost
DB_DATABASE: db_name
DB_USERNAME: root
DB_PASSWORD: pwd
DB_SOCKET: /cloudsql/project_name:europe-west1:db_name

beta_settings:
# for Cloud SQL, set this value to the Cloud SQL connection name,
# e.g. "project:region:cloudsql-instance"
cloud_sql_instances: "project_name:europe-west1:db_name"
```

Composer file has this section

```
  "post-deploy-cmd": [
        "chmod -R 777 bootstrap\/cache"
    ]
```

Did anyone face this issue? just got stuck with this and have no idea how to fix it. Thank you!

Comment: You need to set the file system to use gae.  Have you run the gae:setup command?

Comment: yep, it created new files in config directory

Comment: It does sound like it is using the local directory to store files so the package may not be installed correctly. Try changing the filesystem env variable or adding it.

Comment: thank you for your help, i've overridden this variable in app.yaml  - still have the same error

Comment: Did you get to the bottom of this? If not, can you post what you added to your env file file.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Seems like i've misunderstood things, trying to get app work on google standard env with settings for flexible env.